# how to take space separated integer inputs in int variables in java?

Tags: java, input

I tried this I want to input in integers, i don't want too use a string or array...

```
int sh=0,sm=0,eh=0,em=0;
t=sc.nextInt();
for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
{
      sh=sc.nextInt();
      sm=sc.nextInt();
      eh=sc.nextInt();
      em=sc.nextInt();
}
```

I want to take input as

```
2
1 44 2 14
2 33 5 12
```

There are 4 integers space separated in one line and then the next same as above line how I can?

Comment: how many integer can be there in one line?

Comment: 4 integers in one line

Comment: you need to use next() method. read full line in 1 time. then seprate it by the help of space using string pattern method. store in array or in same variable you want.

Comment: downvoters should give a reason to new users.

Comment: but I want to take them in int not in string

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `nextLine()` method. Read full line in 1 time. Then separate it by the help of space using string split method. Store in array or in same variable you want.

```
for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
{
    String s=sc.nextLine();
    int a[] = new int[4];
    String[] parts = s.split("\\s+");

    sh=Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
    sm=Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
    eh=Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);
    em=Integer.parseInt(parts[3]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `nextLine()` method and `Integer.parseOf()`.
See short example below:

```
    int sh, sm, eh, em;
    int numberOfLines = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLines; ++i) {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        String[] s = line.split(" ");
        sh = Integer.parseInt(s[0]);
        sm = Integer.parseInt(s[0]);
        eh = Integer.parseInt(s[0]);
        em = Integer.parseInt(s[0]);
    }
```

Without `Integer.parse()`:

```
        int sh, sm, eh, em;
        int numberOfLines = scanner.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLines; ++i) {
            sh = scanner.nextInt();
            sm = scanner.nextInt();
            eh = scanner.nextInt();
            em = scanner.nextInt();
        }
```

Comment: Is there another method so that I don't have to use an array and string

Comment: @NavnathGunjal no, there is no method that will convert your String to n- int variables

Comment: Whats the reason? :)

Comment: it is simple if possible :)